# Is it possible to return a hash with named keys form an ActiveRecord group query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

The following query works as expected:

```
Purchase.all.group( :user_id ).sum( :price )
```

It returns an array of hashes:

```
[{ 1 : 234 }, ...
```

Is there a way to return an array of hashes **with keys**?

```
[{ id : 1, price : 234 }, ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return an ActiveRecord::Relation with a single query.

```
Purchase.select("user_id as id, sum(price) as price").group("user_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do:

```
Purchase.all.group(:user_id).sum(:price).map do |k, v| 
  {
    id: k.keys.pop, 
    price: k.values.pop
  }
end
```

Although a bit hacky, works.

Comment: I came up with `map{ |k,v| { id: k, price:v }`. But it would be nicer if there were a Rails way of doing it.